# How to allocate custom time in UILocalnotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, uilocalnotification

```
    - (void)scheduleNotification :(int) rowNo
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        NSString *descriptionBody=[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:rowNo]objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];

        NSLog(@"%@",descriptionBody);

        notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:notif.alertBody
                                                             forKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey"];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

    }
}
```

I have a column name frequency which is fetched from Sqldb where it contains the number of times notification should appear for a particular cell.
if frequency = 3 ..the notification should fire say 8 AM , 2PM then 8PM
if frequency = 4 ..the notification should fire say 8 AM , 12PM , 4PM then 8PM.

Is there a way to do it?   If anyone can help me that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can specify value for repeatInterval only of type NSCalendarUnit (day, week, month). So, I think, You need to create several Notifications with different fireDate, and specify for them repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit
For example,

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
notification1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:SOME_INTERVAL sinceDate:currentTime];
notification1.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

notification2.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:SOME_INTERVAL * 2 sinceDate:currentTime];
notification2.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

After user viewed some of notifications - You can cancel them.

**Update.**

You can also create NSDate from different components like this:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setWeekday:2]; // Monday
[components setWeekdayOrdinal:1]; // The first Monday in the month
[components setMonth:5]; // May
[components setYear:2013];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                     initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

Also You can set hour, minutes, seconds, timezone and other parameters.

Comment: can i choose like if freq = 4 fireDate at  8 AM , 12PM , 4PM then 8PM. using ur method ? (since freq is fetched from db which has number of times notification should fire)
shall i mail my proj so tht u will have clear idea

Comment: Can u help me with this problem .if u want i'll mail my proj .if thats ok with u

Comment: if you want you may send project to me, but I do not know when I'll be able to watch your project (today, tomorrow).

Comment: sure. see if u were able to rectify it